# How can I re-use Vuetify colors within my components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify provides various components such as the success alert below which uses a few different shades of green

[image]

If I want to match these colors within my components, I could just copy-paste the hex values from the browser's dev tools, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way. For example, does Vuetify provide some SASS variables or CSS classes that I can import into my components?

Using the alert above as an example, within my components how can I match the light green background color or the darker green used for the text color?

Comment: Vuetify uses standard theme colours for alerts, like "warning", "error" and "success" for the one you presented. You can match the colours by using the same in your template: `color="success"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are SASS variables and CSS classes in `Vuetify`.

> Out of the box you get access to all colors in the Material Design spec through sass and javascript. These values can be used within your style sheets, your component files and on actual components via the color class system.

You can find further information here: [Colors | Classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/)

On the same page, ([SASS Color Pack](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#sass-color-pack), different anchor), you find information about the usage of SASS Color Pack. Please be aware of the hint in the documentation:

> You must configure your webpack setup to use sass. If you are using a pre-made template this will already be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the colors as part of your theme like below :

```
export default new Vuetify({

    theme: {
        dark: true,
        themes: {
          dark: {
            primary: "#99CC11",
            secondary: "#99CC11",
            accent: "#cddc39",
            error: "#7E57C2",
            warning: "#7E57C2",
            info: "#2196f3",
            success: "#8bc34a",
          },
          },
        },
});
```

Then just use the class as a prop :

```
<v-btn
      text
      rounded
      class="primary--text mx-1"
      to="/signin"
      v-if="authState !== 'signedin'"
    >
```

Comment: I want to re-use the colors defined by Vuetify, not duplicate them

Comment: You can use them in a class of each component : <div class="red"> or <span class="red--text"> , more info here : https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `var(--v-primary-base)` 
Replace 'primary' above with any existing variable i.e [primary, secondary, accent, error, ....]

**Usage** 
background-color: var(--v-primary-base);

***This can be used directly in your CSS.***